# Which is the commensurator of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ in $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I alredy know that the commensurator is $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Q)$ and I have alredy proved that if a matrix $M$ is in $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Q)$ then it is the commensurator too. But the other part I can't prove it, i.e. I don't know how to prove that $comm_{SL(n,\mathbb R)}(SL(n,\mathbb Z))\subset SL(n,\mathbb Q)$ so anyone could help me please

Comment: There might be an interesting question here, but it is very unclear what you are asking. Perhaps you can give more detail of what parts of the proof you know and a more exact description of where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, I have alredy proved that $comm_{SL(n,\mathbb R)}(SL(n,\mathbb Z))\subset SL(n,\mathbb Q)$, but I don't know how to prove that $SL(n,\mathbb Q)\subset comm_{SL(n,\mathbb R)} (SL(n,\mathbb Z))$, thanks

Comment: Now I'm confused. The body of your question says you don't know how to prove one direction $comm_{SL(n,\mathbb R)}(SL(n,\mathbb Z))\subset SL(n,\mathbb Q)$, whereas your comment says you don't know how to prove the other direction $SL(n,\mathbb Q) \subset comm_{SL(n,\mathbb R)}(SL(n,\mathbb Z))$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, what I want to prove is that $comm_{SL(n,\mathbb R)}(SL(n,\mathbb Z))\subset SL(n,\mathbb Q)$, could you help me?